# comb filter design in wireless communication

Tags: filters, filter-design

How can I implement comb filter in reducing noise in wireless communication?
I am new in signal processing and right now I am still learning about the comb filter. Can I use it to reduce/filter noise in wireless communication?

Comment: That's a broad question. Do you have a specific noise source in mind? Does the noise contaminate the audio or the wireless signal?

Comment: thats the thing. I have no idea what type of research that i should do about wireless communication. i need some suggestion from you. can you give some idea about what should do for my final year project related to wireless communication. A simple one should be okay.